# Prove Trichotomy and Multiplicative Ordering for Integers

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, foundations

Prove the following properties of $\mathbb{Z}$:

(a) (Trichotomy) For any $x, y ∈ \mathbb{Z}$, precisely one of $x < y$, $x = y$, $x > y$ is true.

(b) (Multiplicative ordering) For $x, y,z ∈ \mathbb{Z}$, if $x < y$ and $z > 0$ then $x ⊗ z < y ⊗ z$.

I have done part (a) as follows: 
Since $x, y ∈ \mathbb{Z}$, $x-y ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ by the Closure Property of Integers (Subtraction). As  $x-y<0$ or $x-y>0$ or $x-y=0$, it follows that either $x<y$ or $x>y$ or $x=y$ respectively.

Another way I was thinking of doing part (a) is:

$∀x,y∈\mathbb{Z}:x\le y∨y\ge x$

$∀x.y∈\mathbb{Z}:x\le y∨x\ge y$

$∀x,y∈\mathbb{Z}:(x=y∨x<y)∨(x=y∨x>y) $

$∀x,y∈\mathbb{Z}:x<y∨x=y∨x>y$

Are any of the above methods sufficient to solve part (a)? Also, is this related to part (b) since I am unable to progress in (b).

Comment: No.  How is 0 < defined?

Comment: For x != y, wouldn't x-y>0 be defined for x,y in Z?

Comment: No.  Define 0 < k for any k in Z.